# Динамическая проверка данных в Форме Google

Tags: google-spreadsheet, google-apps-script, google-forms

Google Форма содержит следующие поля:

- текстовое поле "Телефон"
- поле "Капча"

Основное поведение. Пользователь заполняет поля. Поле телефон проверяется с загруженным ранее списком номеров (импортируется из CSV или Excel заранее). 3-4 раза в месяц список номеров будет обновляется.

Требования. В ответ Пользователь должен получить сообщение, что такого номера нет, либо что такой номер найден в базе.

Посоветуйте подход или подходы, которые надо совместить для решения этой задачи?
Как получить данные кто, откуда, во сколько, что искал, и какой результат получил? Это требуется для отчетов.

Comment: Поясните задачу. Формы не обладают обратной связью с сервером, поэтому проверить наличие телефона можно только в статическом списке. Если пользователей не много, то можно настроить триггер, который после отправки нового номера будет обновлять сам список Форму. Это то что вы ищите?

Comment: список будет большой, как понимаю вариант возможен если этот список будет уже выгружен на страницу. тогда мне формы не подходят

Comment: Отличное решение. Вы можете использовать Google Apps Script, создав свою форму.

Answer (score 0):

С большой долей вероятности эту задачу нельзя решить в той форме, которую вы выбрали. Google Формы не имеют динамической связи с сервером. Они статичны. Скрипты в них предназначены для извлечения (и только) уже полученных данных, а также для изменения поведения Формы как объекта опроса/исслелования/тестирования. См. [tags/google-apps-script/info](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)

Для решения этого вопроса можно использовать Google Apps Script, опубликовав как веб-приложение. Но они обрабатывают очень скудное количество данных между клиентом и сервером, поэтому достойного трекинга и таргетинга не получится, если хорошенько не настроить Google Analytics.